# Python3 Pygame: Tuple Type Error for draw.circle

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, python-3.7

I'm a beginner, so please excuse me if the information given might be incomplete.

I'm trying to draw a circle with pygame by calling the display method of my "Particle" object; I need the object since I'll be creating many of them. The error I get ("TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)") refers to the line "pygame.draw.circle".

[image]

Since I am really at my wits end I've included the complete code below.

Code:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

# COLORS
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

# SCREEN
scr_width = 1400
scr_height = 600
scr_bckgr_color = WHITE
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scr_width,scr_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Animation")
screen.fill(scr_bckgr_color)

#PARTICLE CLASS
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, position, radius, color):
        self.x = position[0],
        self.y = position[1],
        self.radius = radius,
        self.color = color,
        self.thickness = 0

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius, self.thickness)

# DRAW PARTICLES
Particle1 = Particle((200, 200), 15, BLACK)
Particle1.display()

#pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (200,200), 15, 0)
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Remove the `,` at the end of the lines:

> ```py
> self.x = position[0],
> self.y = position[1],
> self.radius = radius,
> self.color = color,
> ```

When you put a `,` at the end of a line a tuple object is constructed. Tupels are not formed by the comma operator. See [Python - 5.3. Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Remove the commas to fix your code:

```py
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, position, radius, color):
        self.x = position[0]
        self.y = position[1]
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.thickness = 0
```